# why does it compile error when i only #include<math.h>

Tags: c++11, ubuntu-16.04, glibc, gcc5

i upgrade gcc to 5.4, it seems to be ok except math.h

when i write a hello.cpp like the following:

```
#include<math.h>
int main(){return 0;}
```

then i compile the above cpp with gcc 5.4, g++ 5.4

```
g++ hello.cpp
```

errors happen

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h:70:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
                ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:65:16: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (_Mdouble_ __x));
                ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:22: error: ‘sincos’ has not been declared
 __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
                      ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:29: error: expected identifier before ‘,’ token
 __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
                             ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:3: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
```

when i downgrade to gcc 4.8, 4.9, this problem still happens

Comment: gcc 5.4 is pretty old. The current release is 9.3. Can you update to something newer? Are your `gcc` and `libc6-dev` packages both up to date?

Comment: @KeithThompson gcc5.4 run good in my other service, i use `apt-get install gcc-5.4`, and then `apt-get install build-essential`, so gcc and libc6-dev are  up to date

Comment: i also try to remove all the gcc and g++ version and  apt-get install from version 4.8, 4.9, to 5.4, but it doesnot help. i mean gcc runs good without #include<math.h> like above . So i don't know what to do, it's there something i forget to install while upgrade gcc?

Comment: A Google search for "mathcalls.h" "expected constructor" indicates that others have run into this problem. I didn't see a solution in the first few results. Perhaps if your patience exceeds mine you'll find something.

Comment: @KeithThompson so a possible solution is to reinstall my system?, my god, it suck

Comment: I don't know. As I said, others have encountered the same problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution. Reinstallation *shouldn't* be necessary, but if Ubuntu 16.04 (which is also rather old, BTW) had this problem in general it never would have gone out the door. Have you dived into the Google search results I referred to? I'd try `sudo apt-get upgrade` (`man apt-get` first) to make sure all your packages are up to date. If you've been considering updating your system anyway (18.04 LTS is current, 20.04 LTS comes out in just a few weeks) this might be a good excuse.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/q/865844 -- or you might consider clang.

Comment: @KeithThompson thank you guys, apt-get upgrade do help me a lot,

Comment: Does that mean it solved the problem?

Comment: yes @KeithThompson

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept an answer. (It's perfectly ok to accept your own answer.) But please see my comment on your answer and perhaps consider updating it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not reproducuble for me.

```
g++ hello.cpp -ansi -Wall -pedantic
```

Compiles without error. And runs:

Valgrind reports no errors upon running.

```
==100412== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Something is wrong with the poster's installation. Also, as others have said, upgrade gcc.

Comment: I don't know why this should be needed, but try the -lm flag.

Comment: And do upgrade both your Ubuntu and gcc. I don't see much point in spending resources on obsolete systems when newer ones are available?

Comment: thanks man anyway, apt-get install linux-libc-dev help me a lot

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
apt-get install linux-libc-dev
```

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that that particular command was what solved the problem. `linux-libc-dev` is "Linux Kernel Headers for development". Your program does nothing that should depend on kernel headers. You mentioned in comments that `apt-get upgrade` was what solved the problem, which seems more plausible. That would probably have updated multiple packages, and there's no good way to tell which one actually solved your problem.